# Getting the frequency and the amplitude of a wav

Tags: c, audio

I'm wanting to get the frequency and the amplitude of a wav or ogg file in C langage and I want to save them on a list (maybe of each measure at each step of time)

Thank you.

I've firstly tried to record my microphone the instantly get theses datas but it seems impossible

I'm wanting a function where I put an sound file and that return a list composed of [f1,A1,f2,A2,....,fn,An] with f1 the frequency during [0,step]
f2 during [step, 2*step] et caetera.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking about dynamic microphone input or analysing a sound file. Getting the amplitude is easier than getting the frequency - FFT? Either way, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: hum, i see, sorry i didn't have understand. At first I wanted about the dynamic microphone but finally i've decided to do it on a sound file. And i don't really find any functionnal fft algorithm in C

Comment: Do you intend to program the FFT yourself or are you asking for a recommendation of an existing library?

Comment: In fact I think i'm asking for a recommendation of an existing library because i'm short on time. And i also don't know how to open a .wav file in C

Comment: This question is asked with amazing frequency.   What you're asking for is called *source separation* - which is a problem regularly the subject of PhDs.  It's theoretically impossible to achieve perfectly.  It's well beyond the answer of a StackOverflow question